# Array.GetValue Results in an error: "Only single dimensional arrays are supported"

Tags: c#, arrays

I cannot solve this issue and I search a lot about this problem.

In Visual Studio I am running software that must create an Array which looks like this in code:

```
Array arrays;
```

It means that the type is not known.
This array is a simple array of doubles, but it comes from COM, so I need to cast it:

```
double a = (double)arrays.GetValue(index);
```

In most software and simple Console Application this works without problems.
But in Unity I get the error:

```
ArgumentException: Only single dimensional arrays are supported for the requested action.
System.Array.GetValue (System.Int32 index) (at <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0)
```

Can someone give me an advice how can I retrieve values from that array without getting this exception?

Comment: How many dimensions does `arrays` have (`arrays.Rank`)?

Comment: The rank is 0 I do not know why...
I seems that this line of code in ConsoleApplication works, but in Unity do not:
FaroScan.libRef.getXYZScanPoints2(scan_id, 0, i, scanNumRows, out arrays, out arrays1);

Comment: The rank seems to be always 0 and length is a random number i.e. 7 0 7602291 108
It seems that unity uses totally different compiler and I do not know how to solve it...

Comment: You could try Lists. Maybe the problem is the Array is not initialized ?